# ¿Por qué sizeof de un dato no es igual al sizeof de sus miembros?

Tags: c++, sizeof, padding

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
struct datos
{
    char c;
    int i;
    long l;
};

#define SO(x) #x << " = " << x

int main()
{
    datos d;

    std::cout
        << SO(sizeof(d)) << '\n'
        << SO(sizeof(d.c)) << '\n'
        << SO(sizeof(d.i)) << '\n'
        << SO(sizeof(d.l)) << '\n'
        << SO(sizeof(char) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(long)) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Que produce la siguiente salida:

> ```
> sizeof(d) = 16
> sizeof(d.c) = 1
> sizeof(d.i) = 4
> sizeof(d.l) = 8
> sizeof(char) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(long) = 13
> ```

Hace tiempo que finalicé mis estudios de primaria, pero la última vez que lo comprobé sumar uno, cuatro y ocho resultaba en trece; pero al solicitar el tamaño de `datos` me devuelve dieciséis, que no es la suma de uno, cuatro y ocho.

¿Qué está pasando?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esto se debe a una decisión que toma el compilador a la hora de generar el tipo de manera que coincida con múltiplos del tamaño de la [palabra de procesador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palabra_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

#### Palabra de procesador.

La palabra de procesador<sup>1</sup> indica, a grandes rasgos, cuántos bits puede procesar un procesador en una sola operación. Como analogía podemos imaginar un polígrafo, cuantas más agujas tiene más rayas puede dibujar a la vez:

[image]

La palabra de procesador también nos indica el tamaño de los datos que pueden viajar a través del [bus](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(inform%C3%A1tica)) en cada ciclo; por ejemplo: Un procesador de 16 bits tardará dos ciclos de bus en enviar un entero de 32 bits.

#### Alineación en memoria.

Dado que `int` en tu sistema parece ocupar 4 bytes, tu palabra de procesador seguramente sea de 32 bits. ¿Cuál es el tamaño en bits de la estructura `datos`?

```
| <----------------- datos 13 * 8 = 104 bits ------------------> |
|char|        int        |                 long                  |
| 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
```

El tamaño deberían ser 13 bytes (104 bits), siendo la palabra de procesador 32 bits, obtenemos que la estructura `datos` ocupa 3,25 palabras de procesador; esto supone que para leer una instancia de la estructura necesitaremos 4 lecturas de las cuales, en la última ignoraremos los 3 últimos bytes leídos.

Si tras esta instancia de `datos` de 104 bits almacenamos otra, su dirección de memoria estaría desalineada 1 byte respecto a los múltiplos de la palabra de procesador, igualmente deberá realizar 4 lecturas pero después de leer tendrá que alinear los datos descartando el primer byte y después desplazando los datos un byte a la izquierda<sup>2</sup>.

Para evitar este trabajo de más, los objetos se crean de manera que ocupen múltiplos de la palabra de procesador, así que la estructura `datos` en realidad tiene este aspecto en memoria:

```
| <------------ datos 13 * 8 bits + "relleno" 3 * 8 bits = 128 bits -----------> |
|        char        |        int        |                 long                  |
| 1  | re |lle | no  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
```

En total la estructura acaba ocupando 16 bytes, que son los 13 originales mas los 3 de relleno para hacer que su tamaño sea múltiplo de la palabra de procesador (4 bytes).

¿Cómo se que el relleno está entre `datos::c` y `datos::i`? Porque también se está alineando la información en el interior de la estructura `datos`; sin la alineación `datos::i` estaría a caballo entre dos palabras de procesador y requeriría dos lecturas (y re-alineación) para ser leído. También porque podemos comprobar la dirección de cada elemento, con este código:

```
struct datos
{
    char c;
    int i;
    long l;
};

#define DISTANCIA(x, y) #x << " - " << #y << " = " << ((long long)((void*)&x) - (long long)((void*)&y))

int main()
{
    datos d;

    std::cout
        << DISTANCIA(d.c, d) << '\n'
        << DISTANCIA(d.i, d) << '\n'
        << DISTANCIA(d.l, d) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Obtenemos la siguiente salida:

> ```
> d.c - d = 0
> d.i - d = 4
> d.l - d = 8
> ```

Que nos demuestra que entre cada dato de la estructura `datos` hay una distancia de 4 bytes.

#### Alinear a mi gusto.

Si por algún motivo quieres evitar que el compilador decida el tamaño de tus estructuras (puede que las estés serializando) puedes usar el atributo `__attribute__((packed))` de GCC y CLang o `#pragma pack(1)` en MSVC.

`MSVC`

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct datos
{
    char c;
    int i;
    long l;
};
```

`GCC`/`CLang`

```
struct datos
{
    char c;
    int i;
    long l;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Con estos cambios, el siguiente código:

```
#define SO(x) #x << " = " << x
#define DISTANCIA(x, y) #x << " - " << #y << " = " << ((long long)((void*)&x) - (long long)((void*)&y))

int main()
{
    datos d;

    std::cout
        << SO(sizeof(d)) << '\n'
        << SO(sizeof(d.c)) << '\n'
        << SO(sizeof(d.i)) << '\n'
        << SO(sizeof(d.l)) << '\n'
        << SO(sizeof(char) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(long)) << '\n';

    std::cout
        << DISTANCIA(d.c, d) << '\n'
        << DISTANCIA(d.i, d) << '\n'
        << DISTANCIA(d.l, d) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Produce la siguiente salida:

> ```
> sizeof(d) = 13
> sizeof(d.c) = 1
> sizeof(d.i) = 4
> sizeof(d.l) = 8
> sizeof(char) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(long) = 13
> d.c - d = 0
> d.i - d = 1
> d.l - d = 5
> ```

En que vemos que el tamaño de la estructura `datos` ha pasado a 13 y la distancia entre `datos::c` y `datos::i` es de 1 byte (el tamaño de `datos::c`).

---

<sup>1</sup>No tiene nada de bíblico.

<sup>2</sup>Esto es conceptualmente, el procesador puede leer la memoria de otra manera.

Comment: ¡Explicación genial! Aunque recuerda que el operador `sizeof` no devuelve exactamente el tamaño en bytes, sino el tamaño en tamaños de `char` (`sizeof(char)` siempre da `1` aunque un `char` ocupe más de 1 byte). Para saber exactamente el tamaño en bytes sin margen de error tendrías que multiplicarlo por la macro `CHAR_BIT` de *limits.h* y dividirlo por `8` (aunque en la mayoría de los casos como el ejemplo, un `char` es `1` byte).

Comment: Me temo que no @CarlosA.Gómez [en el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) indica literalmente **§ 5.3.3 Sizeof** *The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand.* (El operador `sizeof` devuelve el número de bytes en la representación del objeto que sea su operando).

Comment: In the programming languages C and C++, the unary operator sizeof generates the size of a variable or datatype, measured in the number of char size storage units required for the type. As such, the construct sizeof (char) is guaranteed to be 1. The actual number of bits of type char is specified by the preprocessor macro CHAR_BIT, defined in the include file limits.h. On most modern systems this is eight bits. The result has an unsigned integral type that is usually denoted by size_t.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

Comment: Está muy bien la Wikipedia, pero yo estoy citando el estándar de [tag:c++] :) por otro lado la constante `CHAR_BIT` perteneciente a la cabecera `<limits.h>` corresponde a [tag:c] (no C++). `CHAR_BIT` sólo existe en C++ por retrocompatibilidad con C. `sizeof` en C y en C++ tiene significados distintos.

Comment: Si en C++ está fijado como 1 byte el tamaño de `sizeof(char)` no lo sé. En C, bytes se refiere a bytes de C, que es el tamaño de un `char`.  C considera byte el tamaño de un `char`, no 8 bits.

Comment: En C++ `sizeof` devuelve el tamaño en bytes del objeto. Así está en [el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) y **todos** los compiladores deben seguir el estándar. En C++ `sizeof(char)` y todas sus variantes está prefijado para devolver 1: ***§ 5.3.3 Sizeof** `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)` and
`sizeof(unsigned char)` are `1`*

Comment: Sacado del estándar: The fundamental storage unit in the C ++ memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8  encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation  defined

Comment: Es decir, cuando el estándar habla de byte, no se refiere a 8 bits, sino al tamaño mínimo para contener un `char`. Ergo, no tiene por qué ser 8 bits.

Comment: Estás citando **§ 1.7 The C++ memory model**, que describe el modelo de memoria e indica el tamaño de la unidad mínima de memoria (suficiente para contener cualquier carácter). Pero no indica que el resultado de `sizeof` se mida en `char`. El resultado de `sizeof` se mide en bytes, tal y como se indica en **§ 5.3.3 Sizeof**.

Comment: Se mide en bytes, pero byte no significa 8 bits:  C++ standards borrows from C standards and borrows CHAR_BIT macro which specifies number of bits in a byte in climits.h : Section C3 , Table 150 6. In C 99 standards ( ISO/IEC 9899:1999 ), minimum char bits is guaranteed to be 8 bits in section 5.2.4.2.1 ( Sizes of integer types) :

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62783/discussion-between-paperbirdmaster-and-carlos-a-gomez).