# ¿Por qué el tamaño de la estructura no es igual a la suma de los tamaños de cada miembro de la estructura?

Tags: c

Tengo unas dudas que me surgieron al hacer este programa en cuestión de memoria.

Mi variable `char` de memoria tiene 30 bits, `int` 4 bits y `float` 4 bits, por lo cual da 38 bits la suma pero el tamaño de la estructura es de 40 bits, donde, como o por que hay 2 bits de mas. Y de igual manera para las direcciones, ya que tengo de diferencia 48 posiciones cuando deberían de ser 38 posiciones de diferencia para cada una de las estructuras para `empleado1`, `empleado2`, etc. ¿A que se debe esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct empresa
    {
        char nombre[30];
        float salario;
        int faltas;
    };
    
    struct empresa empleado1={"Maria", 176.22, 2}; 
    struct empresa empleado2={"Cesar", 123.22, 0}; 
    struct empresa empleado3={"Fernanda", 185.56, 1}; 

    struct empresa*emp1;
    emp1=&empleado1;
    struct empresa*emp2;
    emp2=&empleado2;
    struct empresa*emp3;
    emp3=&empleado3;
    
    
    printf("Tamaño nombre: %d\n", sizeof(empleado1.nombre));
    printf("Tamaño salario: %d\n", sizeof(empleado1.salario));
    printf("Tamaño faltas: %d\n\n", sizeof(empleado1.faltas));

    printf("Tamaño struc: %d\n\n", sizeof(struct empresa));

    printf("Direccion: %d\n", emp1->nombre);
    printf("Direccion: %d\n", emp2->nombre);
    printf("Direccion: %d\n", emp3->nombre);
}
```

Comment: Debe ser `bytes`, no `bits`. Anyway, el compilador alinea las variables en memoria para que empiecen en múltiplos de algún valor (depende de la arquitectura) por razones de eficiencia. En este caso, alinea en múltiplos de 8 bytes.

Comment: Pregunta duplicada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90360/por-qu%C3%A9-sizeof-de-un-dato-no-es-igual-al-sizeof-de-sus-miembros?rq=1